# Google Geocode and Directions api use case

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

This is more of a non-technical question, but here goes.

I have authored several tools that can make use of use of the Google Geocode and Directions Web APIs as part of some "plugin/extension" type software I have written (but not released) for a desktop-based commercial GIS application. These tools of course adheer to the 2500 geocodes/day limit and a 10 request/second throtle. I have written several other geocoding/directions tools that hit off other free/unlimited web APIs (ESRI, OSM, etc.). Since Google is so well known, I would like to include the Google APIs as well. However, in reading the Google API Terms of Service https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_12, my use case of a non-web based application seems a bit legally vague... Some more details: My software download is free, however has a relatively small processing limit (< 10 geocodes/routes) in place unless a full license is purchased (from me). For the Google-based tools, my GUI is set up to include Google 'Client Id' and 'Digital Signature' parameters (with explainations and weblinks) so that end users can make use of their Google Business License. Additionally, my software encodes the returned geocode/direction results into standard GIS formats, and can alter the output coordinate system. My software doesn't display the geocode/directions results on a 'Google Map' base layer persay, but doesn't neccessarily display it on another 'Map' either (example: a 'Bing Map'). Results are displayed on a canvas capable of displaying any geospatial data layers. The Geocoding/Directions toolsets, of which the 'Google API' would be an optional paramter as woulld 'OSM API' and 'ESRI API', are a subset (but important subset) of the overall software which does many other things unrelated to geocoding/directions. At any rate, I would like to include a 'Google API' option for my Geocoding/Routing toolset.

My basic question is: Provided the use case above, can I in good faith include the Google Geocode/Directions Web APIs in my software?  If the answer is 'No', are there any use cases where Google Geocode and Directions Web APIs could be used in my software?

Any response (especially from Google Maps staff!) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is against their Terms of Services. Below are links and snippets from the pages. I recently deal with this issue at my job.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/
Note: the Directions API may only be used in conjunction with displaying results on a Google map; using Directions data without displaying a map for which directions data was requested is prohibited. Additionally, calculation of directions generates copyrights and warnings which must be displayed to the user in some fashion. For complete details on allowed usage, consult the Maps API Terms of Service License Restrictions.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/
Note: the Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google map; geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited. For complete details on allowed usage, consult the Maps API Terms of Service License Restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Although that question was asked back in 2013, here is an excerpt from the current Google Maps APIs FAQ, as of March 21, 2016.

***Can I use Google Maps in my non-Web application?**

Yes, the Google Maps APIs can now be used in desktop applications, provided that they adhere to the other restrictions of the Terms of Service. Note that in order for a desktop application to be deemed "publicly accessible", there must be a publicly accessible webpage from which it can be downloaded. See Section 9.1 of the Terms of Service for more information.*

So it's "now" possible under certain conditions.